# wpf + combobox keybinding

Tags: wpf, combobox, key-bindings

I would like to know if someone has a somple example of how to use keybindings with a comboBox control, because I would like to use keybindings to capture the up arrow and down arrow keys.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is super simple to capture Keys in WPF. You simple add a `PreviewKeyDown` event in WPF.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication13.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox Name="myComboBox" PreviewKeyDown="MyComboBox_PreviewKeyDown"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Then trigger something based on the event in the `code-behind`.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void MyComboBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Down)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Key Down");
        }
        else if (e.Key == Key.Up)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Key Up");
        }
    }

}
```